# All possible combinations of int[][] array

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

I am trying to get only distinct coordinates meaning coordinates `(6,7)` and `(7,6)` are the same. How can I go over an array and only get distinct coordinates? So basically I need all of the combinations of coordinates from an `int[][]` array.

```
ArrayList<Coords> coordinateList = new ArrayList<>();
int[][] coordinates = { {56,80}, {32,26}, {47,85}, {3,4}, {10,19}};


public void findDistinct(int[][] coordinates){
    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < coordinates.length - 1 ; j++) {
            if (i == j) continue;
            Coords coords = new Coords(i, j);
            if(! coordinateList.contains(coords)){
                coordinateList.add(coords);
            }
        }
    }
    for(Coords coords: coordinateList){
        System.out.println(coords);
    }
}


public class Coords{

    private final x;
    private final y;

    public Coords(x,y) {
        this.y = y;
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coords{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The output I would like to have:

```
Coords{x=0, x=1}
Coords{x=0, x=2}
Coords{x=0, x=3}
Coords{x=0, x=4}
Coords{x=1, x=2}
Coords{x=1, x=3}
Coords{x=1, x=4}
Coords{x=2, x=3}
Coords{x=2, x=4}
...
```

But at the moment I get all of the possible variations of the coordinates. How can I change the code to get the result I need?

Comment: You could override `equals` and `hashCode` of `Coords` and use a `HashMap` to keep track of coordinates that you have already seen. The `equals` and `hashCode` implementations should define some order in which `x` and `y` are considered (e.g. always consider the smaller value of `x` and `y` first). For example, `hashCode` could look something like `{ if (this.x < this.y) { return (Integer.toString(this.x) + Integer.toString(this.y)).hashCode(); } else { return (Integer.toString(this.y) + Integer.toString(this.x)).hashCode(); } }`

Comment: What has the content of  the `coordinates` array got to do with question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < coordinates.length; j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < coordinates.length; j++)
```

That way you also no longer need to check `if (i == j)`

Comment: But I seem to be missing 4 combinations when I do it like this. With the 5 `coordinates` that I have given here, I get only 6 combianations, but there should be 10.

Comment: Ah, you aslo need to do `j < coordinates.length` (or `j <= coordinates.length - 1`).

Comment: @Richard With this simplified logic there is no need to check the list if it contains the coordinates so the check `if(! coordinateList.contains(coords))` is irrelevant

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yup, I removed all of the extra checks as the code was working fine without them

Answer (score 1):

coordinateList.contains(coords) is going to check if the obj hashcode match or not. If you want contains method to check if coordinates of the two object matches or not, You have implement hashcode and equals method for Class Coords.

Since You want a unique list of coordinates, consider using Set data structure instead of list since contains is expense operation